# Should I actively vote to close valuable questions?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

In the past, StackOverflow accepted a broader range of questions than it does today. Many of the high-voted questions from 2009 are now considered off-topic. *etc etc you know this bit.*

Anyway a lot of these questions, especially the ones with hundreds of votes, are protected by special features like historical locks, to indicate that more are not welcome but keep the information around. But there are thousands of these and most of them don't have this - most of them aren't even closed.

So when I encounter an old, well-received question that by current standard appears to be off-topic *and is not yet closed or protected*, what should I be doing with it?

e.g. [Cross-platform alternative to COM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/960836/cross-platform-alternative-to-com), which by my reckoning is a question asking for a "book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource" (well, borderline, but that's irrelevant right now) - but is well-put, interesting, and has answers that are probably useful to someone. I don't want to cast a vote that indicates I think this question should be *removed* from the site, because I don't; but I do want to cast a vote that indicates more shouldn't follow it.

Up to now I haven't thought about this and have VtC'd several older positive questions. a) Does this risk entering them into the delete process? b) Alternatively, is close-but-keep an accepted idiom when done without the historical protection?

Comment: History should be preserved, (except for COBOL questions, obviously).

Comment: Mechanically I guess this question is a dup, but the perspective is reversed: this is about questions that *aren't* causing active problems (other than padding out the close review queue) and when my own priority as a voter is on preservation. Not sure the linked one addresses that aspect.